# Regex to change each row "ax^+bx+c=0\\" to "\item$ax^+bx+c=0$"?

Tags: regex

How to replace each row `ax^2+bx+c=0\\` with `\item $ ax^2+bx+c=0 $`?

```
-7 x^2+16 x-9=0 \\
 70 x^2+39 x-18=0 \\
 25-36 x^2=0 \\
 6 x^2-17 x-45=0 \\
 -30 x^2+31 x+6=0 \\
 63 x^2-73 x+20=0 \\
 -16 x^2+10 x-1=0 \\
 28 x^2-15 x-25=0 \\
 42 x^2-47 x-9=0 \\
 -81 x^2-45 x-4=0 \\
 -35 x^2+8 x+3=0 \\
 7 x^2-17 x+6=0 \\
 -72 x^2-83 x-21=0 \\
 9 x^2-21 x-8=0 \\
 -42 x^2+17 x+15=0 \\
 -63 x^2-107 x-40=0 \\
 -20 x^2+3 x+2=0 \\
 -24 x^2+22 x+7=0 \\
 49 x^2-84 x+27=0 \\
 -21 x^2-4 x+32=0 \\
 14 x^2+29 x+12=0 \\
 20 x^2+63 x+49=0 \\
 -49 x^2-35 x-6=0 \\
 -54 x^2-33 x+10=0 \\
 42 x^2-103 x+63=0 \\
 -14 x^2-37 x+42=0 \\
 -21 x^2+23 x-6=0 \\
 -16 x^2+38 x+63=0 \\
 -2 x^2-3 x-1=0 \\
 54 x^2-57 x+10=0 \\
 -9 x^2+30 x-16=0 \\
 30 x^2+47 x-5=0 \\
 -12 x^2-x+63=0 \\
 14 x^2+29 x-15=0 \\
 21 x^2+34 x+8=0 \\
 -21 x^2+67 x-42=0 \\
 6 x^2+11 x-35=0 \\
 -48 x^2-46 x-5=0 \\
 63 x^2+104 x+20=0 \\
 10 x^2-13 x-30=0 \\
 14 x^2-11 x-9=0 \\
 8 x^2-33 x+27=0 \\
 -16 x^2-26 x-3=0 \\
 2 x^2-11 x+14=0 \\
 49 x^2-42 x-40=0 \\
 -18 x^2-41 x+10=0 \\
 -15 x^2+8 x-1=0 \\
 -42 x^2-55 x-8=0 \\
 -3 x^2+13 x-4=0 \\
 -72 x^2+49 x-5=0 \\
 8 x^2+37 x+20=0 \\
 5 x^2-27 x-18=0 \\
 8 x^2-34 x-9=0 \\
 -15 x^2+34 x+16=0 \\
 -48 x^2+70 x-25=0 \\
 20 x^2+72 x+7=0 \\
 5 x^2+8 x+3=0 \\
 16 x^2-40 x+9=0 \\
 60 x^2+4 x-45=0 \\
 9 x^2-68 x+35=0 \\
 -35 x^2-76 x-32=0 \\
 10 x^2+79 x+63=0 \\
 45 x^2+74 x+24=0 \\
 15 x^2-41 x-30=0 \\
 14 x^2+9 x+1=0 \\
 10 x^2-39 x-4=0 \\
 7 x^2-33 x-10=0 \\
 7 x^2+9 x+2=0 \\
 -18 x^2+43 x+5=0 \\
 -63 x^2+10 x+8=0 \\
 10 x^2+x-3=0 \\
 56 x^2+69 x+18=0 \\
 -63 x^2+50 x-8=0 \\
 10 x^2+51 x+5=0 \\
 100 x^2-49=0 \\
 -2 x^2-21 x-49=0 \\
 30 x^2+31 x+5=0 \\
 x^2-9 x+14=0 \\
 -28 x^2-x+2=0 \\
 -30 x^2-19 x+28=0 \\
 25 x^2-25 x-24=0 \\
 27 x^2+69 x+14=0 \\
 -9 x^2+54 x-80=0 \\
 -16 x^2+66 x-35=0 \\
 -63 x^2-20 x+32=0 \\
 -x^2-6 x-5=0 \\
 90 x^2+17 x-56=0 \\
 -20 x^2-67 x-56=0 \\
 -56 x^2+111 x-54=0 \\
 20 x^2+23 x+6=0 \\
 -5 x^2-18 x-16=0 \\
 -60 x^2+8 x+3=0 \\
 9 x^2-29 x+6=0 \\
 25 x^2-10 x-24=0 \\
 15 x^2+2 x-8=0 \\
 -45 x^2-94 x-48=0 \\
 35 x^2-4 x-15=0 \\
 30 x^2+x-42=0 \\
 -7 x^2-44 x-12=0 \\
 35 x^2+36 x-20=0 \\
 -30 x^2+53 x-21=0 \\
 40 x^2+61 x+7=0 \\
 2 x^2+5 x-25=0 \\
 -45 x^2-47 x+40=0 \\
 -4 x^2-37 x-9=0 \\
 35 x^2-29 x-28=0 \\
 42 x^2-25 x-28=0 \\
 -36 x^2+55 x+14=0 \\
 10 x^2-17 x-63=0 \\
 -30 x^2-17 x+2=0 \\
 15 x^2+31 x+14=0 \\
 -32 x^2+84 x-49=0 \\
 x^2-12 x+20=0 \\
 -9 x^2-8 x+1=0 \\
 -4 x^2+27 x+81=0 \\
 18 x^2-25 x-3=0 \\
 -7 x^2+32 x-16=0 \\
 7 x^2-13 x-2=0 \\
 45 x^2+98 x+49=0 \\
 -63 x^2-25 x-2=0 \\
 49 x^2-70 x+24=0 \\
 35 x^2+46 x-16=0 \\
 45 x^2+22 x-80=0 \\
 21 x^2-19 x+4=0 \\
 10 x^2+73 x-56=0 \\
 16 x^2-24 x+9=0 \\
 2 x^2+x-6=0 \\
 -28 x^2-43 x-9=0 \\
 -30 x^2-67 x-36=0 \\
 -6 x^2-47 x-35=0 \\
 -35 x^2-66 x-27=0 \\
 -9 x^2+34 x-21=0 \\
 15 x^2-37 x-8=0 \\
 -7 x^2+38 x-15=0 \\
 -14 x^2+3 x+27=0 \\
 -40 x^2+22 x-3=0 \\
 40 x^2-71 x+21=0 \\
 -63 x^2-16 x+60=0 \\
 -35 x^2+12 x+36=0 \\
 2 x^2+21 x+40=0 \\
 -42 x^2-23 x+5=0 \\
 45 x^2+16 x-5=0 \\
 -56 x^2+113 x-56=0 \\
 4 x^2+27 x+18=0 \\
 -28 x^2+19 x-3=0 \\
 14 x^2-51 x+40=0 \\
 -48 x^2-62 x-9=0 \\
 2 x^2+13 x+21=0 \\
 25 x^2-20 x+3=0 \\
 -14 x^2+27 x-10=0 \\
 60 x^2-44 x-5=0 \\
 50 x^2-5 x-36=0 \\
 -3 x^2-19 x+14=0 \\
 5 x^2-24 x-5=0 \\
 -12 x^2-40 x+63=0 \\
 -30 x^2+59 x-28=0 \\
 -x^2+8 x+9=0 \\
 5 x^2-51 x+10=0 \\
 -8 x^2+22 x-5=0 \\
 -9 x^2+40 x-16=0 \\
 32 x^2-92 x+63=0 \\
 30 x^2-89 x+24=0 \\
 -4 x^2-8 x+21=0 \\
 x^2-3 x-10=0 \\
 -9 x^2-85 x-36=0 \\
 -10 x^2-47 x-9=0 \\
 20 x^2-9 x-81=0 \\
 28 x^2+89 x+70=0 \\
 -16 x^2-66 x-35=0 \\
 -35 x^2-16 x+12=0 \\
 63 x^2+8 x-15=0 \\
 -4 x^2-21 x+18=0 \\
 -10 x^2+21 x+49=0 \\
 27 x^2+15 x-8=0 \\
 20 x^2+7 x-6=0 \\
 -8 x^2-71 x+90=0 \\
 15 x^2-28 x+12=0 \\
 -28 x^2-33 x+28=0 \\
 4 x^2-12 x+9=0 \\
 3 x^2+16 x+20=0 \\
 3 x-2 x^2=0 \\
 6 x^2-13 x-28=0 \\
 24 x^2-38 x+15=0 \\
 -9 x^2+26 x+3=0 \\
 42 x^2-53 x+15=0 \\
 35 x^2-76 x+32=0 \\
 -28 x^2-103 x-90=0 \\
 70 x^2-29 x-15=0 \\
 21 x^2+8 x-5=0 \\
 -6 x^2+23 x-7=0 \\
 7 x^2-26 x-45=0 \\
 -32 x^2-36 x+5=0 \\
 8 x^2-49 x+45=0 \\
 10 x^2+13 x-30=0 \\
 -36 x^2+41 x+90=0 \\
 8 x^2-45 x+25=0 \\
 -6 x^2+61 x-63=0 \\
 -3 x^2+4 x+32=0 \\
 -6 x^2+49 x+45=0 \\
 -9 x^2+27 x-14=0 \\
 49 x^2+49 x-30=0 \\
 -48 x^2-22 x+15=0 \\
 40 x^2+77 x+36=0 \\
 -2 x^2+11 x-9=0 \\
 18 x^2-25 x-50=0 \\
 -60 x^2+28 x+49=0 \\
 3 x^2+31 x+70=0 \\
 -8 x^2+57 x-7=0 \\
 -15 x^2+19 x+56=0 \\
 -63 x^2+73 x-20=0 \\
 -5 x^2+31 x-30=0 \\
 -18 x^2-25 x+3=0 \\
 4 x^2+19 x-30=0 \\
 -40 x^2-51 x-14=0 \\
 63 x^2-89 x+30=0 \\
 36 x^2-73 x-18=0 \\
 6 x^2+19 x-7=0 \\
 36 x^2+5 x-50=0 \\
 8 x^2+47 x+35=0 \\
 20 x^2+16 x+3=0 \\
 -81 x^2+99 x-28=0 \\
 36 x^2-41 x+8=0 \\
 25 x^2+5 x-12=0 \\
 -6 x^2-19 x-15=0 \\
 80 x^2+14 x-3=0 \\
 63 x^2+34 x-40=0 \\
 25 x^2+50 x+21=0 \\
 28 x^2+31 x-72=0 \\
 -36 x^2-43 x-12=0 \\
 4 x^2-15 x-25=0 \\
 35 x^2+73 x+18=0 \\
 15 x^2+52 x+45=0 \\
 81 x^2+162 x+80=0 \\
 3 x^2-17 x+24=0 \\
 20 x^2-19 x-6=0 \\
 81 x^2+18 x-8=0 \\
 32 x^2-12 x-35=0 \\
 4 x^2+33 x+35=0 \\
 2 x^2+23 x+63=0 \\
 -70 x^2-61 x-12=0 \\
 -70 x^2+123 x-54=0 \\
 27 x^2+42 x-5=0 \\
 7 x^2+58 x+16=0 \\
 -28 x^2-51 x+27=0 \\
 18 x^2+71 x-45=0 \\
 -63 x^2+4 x+4=0 \\
 -63 x^2-88 x-9=0 \\
 -x^2-19 x-90=0 \\
 -7 x^2-32 x+60=0 \\
 -40 x^2+38 x+15=0 \\
```

Comment: what is your regex engine?

Comment: if your just looking for a result you might start a worksheet on regex101.com

Comment: `^(.+)\\\\$` replace with `\item $ $1 $`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all your lines are in the same format, we can just capture everything in the line except the `\\` at the end, and use it in the substitution.

The regex is:

```
^(.+)\\\\$
```

with multiline option on.

Note how group 1 captures everything except the `\\`.

And you replace with:

```
\item $ $1 $
```

where `$1` means whatever is captured in group 1.